# how does python' set difference work internally?

Tags: python, set

Recently, i am looking through some python modules to understand their behavior and how optimized their implementation are. Can any one tell what algorithm does python use to perform the set difference operations. One possible way to achieve set difference is by using hash tables which will involve an extra N space. I tried to find the source code of set operations but i am not able to find out the code location.  Please help.

Comment: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a6e6efa2f4dd/Objects/setobject.c#l1589

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A set in python is a hash itself. So implementing difference for it is not as hard as you imagine. Looking from a higher level how does one implement set difference? Iterate over one of the collections and add to the result all elements that are not present in the other sequence.

Comment: Is that just your personal guess or do you have a source for this claim? In can think of 4 different ways to compute `c = a.difference(b)`: 1) `c = {x for x in a if x not in b}`; 2) `c = {x for x in b if x not in a}`; 3) `c = copy(a); for x in b: c.remove(x)`; 4) `c = copy(b); for x in a: c.remove(x)`. If one of the two sets is much larger than the other, then these methods are not equivalent at all.